# Issue in uploading image file through test.py in DJango

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Trying to populate a table having a column `models.ImageField(upload_to='dataset/', blank=True)`

the directory dataset is created when I upload image.
but after that `OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect:` is throwing and the image is not saved in the directory `dataset`.

`J:\\BIOMETRICS\\Student_projects\\Biometric-ID-app\\Biometric_App\\biomteric_app\\version 1.0 impl\\biometric_app_root\\media\\dataset\\C:`
this is the url trying to create and throwing the error

Comment: hi, welcome to StackOverflow, can you show us your settings file, you must define the `MEDIA_ROOT` and the `MEDIA_URL` defined, also post your urls.py

Comment: Hi Sammy, the settings is right. The issue was reading the image. I tried to upload the image just by passing the url to the image field. When I fixed this issue the above issue automatically solved. I used SimpleUploadedFile library to read the image and then assigned the value to the image field and it's working fine. Thank you for your support.